# Visual SVN Server Installation Error - Share Drive - Access Denied

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

We are trying to install Visual SVN Server 2.7.1 and trying to place repositories on windows share. We have given all the rights to the share folder but its show the below error while installation of the application.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that server's service account has enough NTFS and share permissions to repositories root directory.

   By default, VisualSVN Server service runs under `Network Service` account. Services that use the Network Service account, access network resources with the credentials of the **computer account**. So if you
   run VisualSVN Server service under "Network Service", then you should grant access to the **computer account** where VisualSVN Server is installed. See http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00022/
2. Don't specify share as the location for your repos on first install. Just install with default settings, then configure permissions to the share and switch to repos on your share.